# Has VHDL-2008 standard type protected type implementations?

Tags: vhdl

I need a shared variable of type 'boolean' in VHDL-2008.

I can't use the standard type BOOLEAN, because it's not a protected type, which is required for *new style* shared variables.

I saw many quick standard type implementations as a protected type and of cause I could write my own set of bools, ints, pos, nats, ... but is this necessary?

**Does VHDL-2008 have a set of such types in a common package?**

Until now, I just saw user implemented protected types.

Here is a [protected BOOLEAN](https://github.com/JimLewis/OSVVM/blob/master/TranscriptPkg.vhd#L83-L97) example from [OSVVM](https://github.com/JimLewis/OSVVM).

```
type LocalBooleanPType is protected 
  procedure Set (A : boolean) ; 
  impure function get return boolean ; 
end protected LocalBooleanPType ; 

type LocalBooleanPType is protected body
  variable GlobalVar : boolean := FALSE ; 
  procedure Set (A : boolean) is
  begin
     GlobalVar := A ; 
  end procedure Set ; 
  impure function get return boolean is
  begin
    return GlobalVar ; 
  end function get ; 
end protected body LocalBooleanPType ;
```

Comment: If you were to look iIEEE Std 1076-2008 Annex D Potentially nonportable constructs, shared variables are listed as not guaranteed to be portable. A shared variable object shall be a protected type (6.4.2.4, para 3). 5.6.1 Protected type definitions "...A protected type implements instantiatiable regions of sequential statements, each of which are guaranteed exclusive access to shared data. Shared data is a set of variable objects that may be potentially accessed as a unit by multiple processes." Are you asking about standardized *method*s? (5.6.2 para 4). (The answer is no.)

Comment: I don't expect that there are protected types with all possible operators, but most examples I have seen have at least a Get/Set interface. But you are right, it's not easy to define a common set of methods which will satisfy most users. *So it's to specific to the use cases so VHDL can't supply a basic implementation?*

Comment: "Shared data is a set of variable objects that may be potentially accessed as a unit by multiple processes" and "Each subprogram specified within a given protected type declaration defines an abstract operation, called a *method*, that operates atomically and exclusively on a single object of the protected type."  A method function is impure and exclusive access is abstract, there's no hardware imperative. There's no widely recognized set of useful objects *and* abstract operations that demonstrates a need for standardization in verification as yet. There are other verification methodologies.

Answer (score 0):

I will post user1155120's comments in an answer, so this question doesn't show as unanswered. Start quote:

If you were to look `IEEE Std 1076-2008 Annex D Potentially nonportable constructs`, shared variables are listed as "not guaranteed to be portable". A shared variable object shall be a protected type (6.4.2.4, para 3).
5.6.1 Protected type definitions:

> ... A protected type implements instantiatiable regions of sequential statements, each of which are guaranteed exclusive access to shared data. Shared data is a set of variable objects that may be potentially accessed as a unit by multiple processes..

Are you asking about standardized methods? (5.6.2 para 4). (The answer is no.)

Furthermore in 5.6.2 :

> Each subprogram specified within a given protected type declaration defines an abstract operation, called a method, that operates atomically and exclusively on a single object of the protected type.

A method function is impure and exclusive access is abstract, there's no hardware imperative. There's no widely recognized set of useful objects and abstract operations that demonstrates a need for standardization in verification as yet. There are other verification methodologies.

All honors go to user155120

Comment: Nice try to get David's reputation ... If you want the answer to get closed, convince him to write an answer. I tried it several times. He is just helping people and doesn't​ want the points.

Comment: Realistically Patrick could answer his own question which I'd personally consider designed to elicit informed opinion. Should he do so, who knows? He might even sway my informed opinion toward a different viewpoint.

Comment: @Paebbels. I think you're misinterpreting my intentions. I'm trying to improve the site. Many people use stackoverflow as a source of information. They for instance have the same question you have, and come to this topic. But then it seems the question has no answers. Well, it has, but it is in the comments (user1155120 seems to do that more often). That's not the idea behind the site: answers should be posted as answers.... I'm not in this for the credits!

Comment: There's a mechanism to promote [pearls, not sand](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) on these sites. There are help center [asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) guidelines where [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) suggests *You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.* Your or my opinion of what improves the site may not be on the mark.

Comment: The guidelines distinguish which questions should be answered. Answering questions of uncertain value in comments at least aids the question author.  See [How to reference material written by others](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) Paebbel's reaction to your answer may include *Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own.* Where in a comment quoting authority (the standard, not me) can be a suggestion to  *Search and research*  (see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Comment: Of course, "pearls" should be promoted, but the voting system covers that already: up-voting the good, down-voting the bad. Furthermore, answering is answering: if you answer the question in the comments -like happened in this topic- you are _still answering the question_. I mean: you cannot claim that you didn't answer the "bad question" by posting an answer in the comments. But this way, because no 'official' answers was posted in this case, the question will still incorrectly pop-up on the [unanswered question list](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/vhdl).

Comment: Then about plagiarism: you shouldn't blindly copy complete text of external sources. But like the like says: you can quote somebody. 
This case is even special: the source is just above the quote.
I'm not in this _at all_ for the credits. I am trying to help improve the site.
This would not be necessary if people would just post their answers as answer, not as comment....
Some discussions have been happening on this topic on Meta: e.g. [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments)

Comment: and [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295292/when-do-you-answer-a-question-in-the-comments-vs-actually-posting-an-answer)